# Social Tables API: Export diagram for event

Tags: social-tables

Is it possible to export the diagram for a Social Tables event through the API (in PDF or an image format)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We do not provide a public API endpoint to export a diagram at this time, but we are considering providing one in the future.

If you're planning a large-scale integration, we would love to take your use case into account when we do release one; you may want to introduce the topic as part of a sales or support conversation for maximum expedience.