# Access to Diagram URL from API

Tags: social-tables

Is there a way to access a diagram PDF through the API? The last question like this was asked over 2 years ago and it was mentioned that it was potentially in the works.([Social Tables API: Export diagram for event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45805869/social-tables-api-export-diagram-for-event))

Alternatively, is there a way to access an event file URL through the API?

Answer (score 0):

We don't really have a way to do it through the api.

There is a bit of a hack you can do from a browser (or possibly via automation of a headless chrome).

If you are logged in and stick /pdf at the end of a diagram URL, it will redirect to the PDF version.

For example:

https://diagram.socialtables.com/diagram/{diagram_id_here}/pdf

Will redirect to https://socialtables-vm3-pdf.s3.amazonaws.com/{unique_id}.pdf

Comment: But if we wanted to just have a link to be able to provide for clients, it wouldn't be possible as they wouldn't be logged in?